# Show current image from node editor on viewport's mesh

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I can't recall a feature in Blender where the user selects a node from material editor, presses a button and that node's image result will be shown on the mesh in the viewport. What is it and how to get it?

Comment: This, I believe, is a feature from the [Node Wrangler](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Node_Wrangler) addon

Comment: If you want to preview image texture on unwrapped mesh then you can with proper image texture node selected enable Texture shading in the viewport (Alt+Z)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos btw which hotkey is what I was talking about? I'm checking out the actions after the install but can't find the one I need

Comment: oh got it, ctrl-shift-left. btw you might convert that comment to an answer, it saved me hours of googling.

Answer (score 2):

This, I believe, is a feature from the [Node Wrangler addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Node_Wrangler)

Never used it myself but it apparently creates a temporary emission shader to act as a texture viewer in the viewport.

Hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse button Click</kbd> as [illustrated in the wiki page by Greg Zaal](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/File:Addon_nodewrangler_viewer.gif).

[image]